# what's the meaning of two vertical bar and colon in linux comman?

Tags: shell

I see a command like this:

```
sudo groupadd www-data || :
```

But I don't know the meaning of || :

I found a saying that `:` aliased to true, this make the whole line silent?

Answer (score 4):

This is to ignore exit status of `sudo groupadd www-data`.

It is a good practice to fail shell script as soon as one of its expressions fails. This protects from hard to catch errors, when you forget to check return code of some command. This is typically achieved by putting following at the very beginning of the shell script:

```
set -e 
set -o pipefail
```

But now what if you want to ignore exit status of one of the commands intentionally? You may temporary disable fail-on-error flag:

```
set +e
sudo groupadd www-data
set -e
```

But this is ugly. To avoid ugliness, we may use OR boolean expression (`||`) with `:` command, which has no effect and always succeeds. Thus, `sudo groupadd www-data || :` is translated as such:
run `sudo groupadd www-data` and, if it fails, run `:`, which can't fail. As such, whether `sudo` fails or not, the return status of overall expression is success and it will never cause script termination.